# How to understand when code needs to be more powerful or more clearly?

Tags: performance, optimization

I'm a new Java Backend Developer Junior. I finally transform my passion into my daily job.

I have a question in my mind that I never answered to.
I know that there are different way of think about code, it's a philosophy after all.

So, my question is: it's better to write optimized (and more complex) code or a more understandable code?

Each solution has its pros and cons. Maybe a more readable code is easier to fix and debug, but the complex version of itself could perform better.

I would like to hear experts' opinions. I hope to be in the right place for asking.

Cheers,

Manuel

Comment: Although your question will rise "opinion based answers" (like this one is) you should always strife for readable code, especially if you expose said code. The exception might be if you *really* will gain a significant performance boost by going "fancy". You might want to (and should) grab a few books about software architecture.

Comment: Two different opinions, as I thought. Thanks both for express your point of view. Thanks @Nikolas to suggest me software architecture. I'll take a look over it.